# How to allow posting form data to a new window in a web app

Tags: web-applications, progressive-web-apps, forms, new-window, http-post

I have a form where users can choose between options that changes the file that can be either downloaded or that are presented in another window (such as a PDF that can be printed).

```
<form action="/pdf" method="post" target="_blank">
    <input type="checkbox" id="show_some_stuff" name="show_some_stuff" value="1"><label for="show_some_stuff">Show some stuff</label>
    (...)
    <input type="submit" name="action" value="Print">
    <input type="submit" name="action" value="Download">
</form>
```

This works great across browsers. But when this form is accessed in a mobile progressive web application (made available by a [web app manifest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Manifest)) the posted values like `show_some_stuff` and `action` are not available in the new window.

Is there a way to get the posted values in the new window?

Answer (score 0):

As it seems not possible to post values to a new window within web applications, and to preserve the post method on forms when accessed outside a web application, I've added this code so that these forms do not open in a new window inside a web application.

```
if (window.matchMedia('(display-mode: standalone)').matches) {
    $("form[target='_blank']").each(function() {
        $(this).removeAttr('target');
    });
}
```

I've been put on the right track by [this article](https://www.stefanjudis.com/blog/three-things-to-consider-before-your-progressive-web-app-goes-standalone/) by [Stefan Judis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4253183/stefan-judis).